# Trigger with data replacement by PHP and MySqL

Tags: php, html, mysql

The code below is postar.php

```php
include "conexao.php";

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT titus.titus, titus.des, titus.link from titus");

while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta));
echo "<div> $postagem-></div>
      <div>
      $postagem->
      $postagem->$postagem-></div>"
```

This one below is podcast.php

```
<!-- Button -->
<form method="post" action="postar.php">
 <button  type="submit" class="pos" >
publish</button>
</form>
```

I need to click on the publish button, so that it contains the latest information from the mysql database and returns it in a post.

In postar.php has a small php code, which aims to replace the information that is titus, des and link

example:

```
titus is sun
des is moon
link is land
```

(data in the database)

so it should look like this:

```
sun
moon
land
```

But when I run the code, only the arrows appear.
I want to know how to solve this and appear the data as a post.

Below contains the database connection code, which is conexao.php

```php
define('HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('USUARIO', 'root');
define('SENHA', '');
define('DB', 'login');

$conexao = mysqli_connect(HOST, USUARIO, SENHA, DB) or die ('Could not connect');
```

And this is the database table:

```
CREATE TABLE titus(
idpod INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
titus VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
des VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
link VARCHAR (300) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idpod`)
);
```

This code aims to make a post, where when adding a new record in the database, I do this posting process, I know that somehow it is possible to do this with trigger, I am not a professional programmer, but I would like to understand this question, thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * from titus
where idpod = (select max(idpod) from titus)");

while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta)){

     echo $postagem = $_POST['titus'] .'<br>';
     echo $postagem = $_POST['des'] .'<br>';
     echo $postagem = $_POST['link'] .'<br>';
```

Answer (score 2):

you should change your code, like this:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT titus, des, link from titus");

while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta));

if ($postagem) {
    echo "<div>titus is $postagem->titus</div>
      <div>des is $postagem->des</div>
      <div>link is $postagem->link</div>";
} else {
    echo "data is empty";
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much !!, now it worked, but it does not replace the titus, des and link data with those in the database, and gave this error: Attention: Trying to get the 'titus' property of the non-object

Comment: @Vitor I edited my code. Let me know, if will not work

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, the errors disappeared, it is showing "the data is empty", but it has a record made on MySql

Comment: Hello, for your code I managed to create a version that worked, thank you very much for your help. I will post to help other people.